# Is there a way to use a variable in a formula, copy pasted using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I'm trying to copy a whole sheet, which includes a couple tables with formulas. I've set up a macro for coyping the sheet with the tables, but when pasted the formula in the tables refer to the previous sheet instead the one which it is on.

```
    Cells.Select
Range("C2").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10/12/2020"
Range("B6:W21").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("B5").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Dim username As String
username = InputBox("What is the starting date of your planning? (In the format mm-dd)")
Range("B5").Value = username
Dim sheetname As String
sheetname = InputBox("What will be the name of the sheet")
ActiveSheet.Name = sheetname
    Range("B25").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=SUM(IF("sheetname"!R6C2:R21C16=[@Activiteit],1,0))"
```

And the "sheetname" in the last line of code I would like to be the variable sheetname.

Comment: Please read [How to avoid using select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your last line should be as follows I believe:

```
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=SUM(IF(" + sheetname + "!R6C2:R21C16=[@Activiteit],1,0))"
```